# Undeclared type in function call in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to iOS development and swift 4. I am following an online tutorial to play around with the ARkit and vision module in iOS.

I am running into a problem where I am trying to call a function to capture the frame from the iphone camera. I am getting an error with the use of undeclared type, even though the tutor did not declare the type.

Please let me know how I am supposed to declare the type.
Here's the code snippet:

```
func captureOutput(_  output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
print("camera was able to capture a frame:", Date())
```

}

below is the error code I am getting:
[image]

Comment: Please also copy and paste the relevant code into your question as text. It's much easier to read, reference, and search.

Comment: And you need to replace all of those placeholders with real code before asking about any errors.

Comment: Did you contact the writer of the tutorial?